# Fastest way to solve Gaussian Integral

Tags: gaussian-integral

The Gaussian integral is defined as
$$\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2}dx.$$

I know there are many ways to solve it, but what would be the fastest you know?

Comment: To put it in Sage.

Comment: Square the integral & convert to polar coordinates ... This is a duplicate of ? (anyone ?)

Comment: @Phicar What a fantastic answer ... you have made me laugh out loud $\ddot \smile$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all the gaussian integral is defined as
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}\mathrm{d}x,$$ but since the function we want to integrate is even, we can easily find the connection between those two.
The fastest way I know, is to use Eulers Reflection formula.
I would start with the substitiution $x^2 = u$. That means that $\mathrm{d}x = \frac{\mathrm{d}u}{2\sqrt{u}}$. We get:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}\mathrm{d}x = 2\int_{0}^{\infty}\cfrac{u^{-\frac{1}{2}}}{2}e^{-u}\mathrm{d}u.$$

If you are familiar with the gamma function you'll see that this integral is equivalent to $\Gamma(\frac{1}{2})$. Now use the Euler Reflection formula
$$\Gamma(z)\Gamma(1-z) = \cfrac{\pi}{\sin{\pi z}}\quad{\Longrightarrow}\quad\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(1-\frac{1}{2}\right) = \cfrac{\pi}{\sin{\frac{\pi}{2}}} $$
Now simplify and take the square root on both sides:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}\mathrm{d}x = \Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) = \sqrt{\pi}$$

Answer (score 3):

> what would be the fastest you know?

given that

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-x^2}dx=\sqrt{\pi}$$

...your integral is exactly the half: $\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$

Comment: Sorry but this is one of the funniest answers I have read. I can not stop laughing while seeing it